# How do I close all outlines in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, editor

I wish to get eclipse to close all it's outlines (or folds?) in it's editor. Is there such an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the last suggestion - I found the answer - right click on any of the little outlining circles and this brings up a menu with a "folding" option - a sub-menu is "collapse all".

Answer (score 0):

right click on one of the source tabs and click "close all"

Comment: Not, the tabs - I mean the outlines - those things you can open and close by clicking on the little plus or minus in the circles on the left of the source code.

Comment: Oh, I don't know. The only thing I can think of for that is to close the one at the top so they all go inside of it. :)